# How can get Unity GUI max x, y position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
void OnGUI() {

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (0,maxY, 100,100 ), "Saldır")) {
            anim.SetBool("Bekle", false);
            anim.SetBool("Saldir", true);
        }
    }
```

this is my code.
I want to get maximum Y position in GUI screen? How can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Screen.height](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-height.html) to obtain the maximum Y-value for your screen. In your case, I'd say `Screen.height - 100`, because you have to subtract the Button's height in order to make it visible.

Obviously, `Screen.width` for the X-value.

Answer (score 0):

if this is about scaling. use a canvas.

but if you have to use (old) GUI, use a matrix:

```
        public void OnGUI(){
//First thing is the matrix
             GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS (Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, Vector3 (Screen.width / 1280, Screen.height / 720, 1));

   //code
        }
```

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/169056/bulletproof-way-to-do-resolution-independant-gui-s.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-matrix.html

and to answer your question use :

Screen.width
Screen.height